bluetooth active but not turning on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
kachi@kachi-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo modprobe btusb
kachi@kachi-HP-Notebook:~$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth 4.0
kachi@kachi-HP-Notebook:~$ groups
kachi adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev users bluetooth lpadmin
kachi@kachi-HP-Notebook:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 

bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enab>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-10-04 13:53:57 WAT; 3min 50s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 30272 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9315)
     Memory: 792.0K (peak: 1.2M)
        CPU: 58ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─30272 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth s>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: Starting SDP server
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init(>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Syste>
Oct 04 13:53:57 kachi-HP-Notebook bluetoothd[30272]: Bluetooth management interface 1>
~
lines 1-22/22 (END)


cd /lib/firmware/brcm && sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/refs/heads/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd  reboot
